# Apache Solr 6.x with JBoss AS 4.0

Tags: java, apache, solr, jboss, integration

Versions after Solr 5.3 does not have solr.war to use in JBoss container (https://wiki.apache.org/solr/WhyNoWar).

But I would like to know what is the best way to integrate Apache Solr 6.x with JBoos AS 4.0.

I have a enterprise application, so I need an easy and convenient way to set up the production environment of my all clientes with Solr and JBoss.

Answer (score 0):

Even if this thing would have many interested followers there is neither standard nor convenient way to setup latest versions of Solr as war. I read this in the Solr Users forum:

> For right now, Solr is still a webapp.  It is not packaged as a .war
>   file, but the information that would have been extracted from a .war
>   file is still there, in exactly the same layout.  It is already
>   exploded, and the included Jetty accesses it as a webapp directly. 
>   You should be able to add the exploded webapp to another container
>   like you would a .war file ... although you are on your own to make it
>   work if you choose this path.

Reference: http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/solr-5-leaving-tomcat-will-I-be-the-only-one-fearing-about-this-td4300065.html